# Running two processes in parallel from makefile

Tags: linux, makefile

I am trying to run both a server and client to run from a makefile:

target:

```
   ./server&
   ./client
```

The problem is that server& never returns the control back even though I assume it should run in the background. It keeps listening for client which is never invoked as the makefile does not seem to get the control back from server. How can I solve this issue?. without writing any additional target or scripts?

Answer (score 35):

You should be able to do this by combining the commands on a single line:

```
target:
     ./server& ./client
```

Make hands commandlines to the shell (`$(SHELL)`) *one line at a time*.

Alternatively, you could define two independent targets:

```
target: run_server run_client

run_server:
     ./server
run_client:
     ./client
```

and run make with the `-j` option to make it parallelize build steps:

```
make -j2
```

This would not appear the most natural solution for launching your program (e.g. for test) but works best when you have large numbers of build rules that can be partly built in parallel. (For a little more control on `make`-s parallellization of targets, see also

> [`.NOTPARALLEL`](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Special-Targets.html)
>
> > If `.NOTPARALLEL` is mentioned as a target, then this invocation of make will be run serially, even if the `‘-j’` option is given. Any recursively invoked make command will still run recipes in parallel (unless its makefile also contains this target). Any prerequisites on this target are ignored.

Answer (score 2):

`server` runs in background. You may put in foreground using command `fg`. And then kill it with Ctrl-C

Or maybe this method: `killall server`

Comment: Thanks guys. Its working now. The change was that client waits infinitely for server to be up and then in make I run client in background and server in foreground. Thanks!!!

Comment: `fg` does not work in make context because each line is executed in a separate shell